# Syntax error in SHOW FIELD FROM

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems with the following statement, I know its probably something small and silly but I cant seem to find the solution.

```
$field_sql = 'SHOW FIELDS FROM '.$table  '  WHERE FIELD '=''.$column';
```

Comment: You have too many quotes - you don't need the ones around the `=`. You're also missing a `.` after `$table`

Comment: You're missing a `.` after `$table`.

Comment: Don't even need the `'`. Turn the whole thing into a `"` string and eliminate the concat operations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a dot and have quotes when you don't need them:

```
$field_sql = 'SHOW FIELDS FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE FIELD = ' . $column;
                                          ^               ^^^          ^
                                          Missing         Removed extra quotes
```

However, for SQL string values, you probably want the quotes, so you can use different quotes than the ones you're using to denote the string:

```
$field_sql = 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `' . $table . '` WHERE FIELD = "' . $column . '"';
```

I also added backticks for the table name.

Comment: Thank you sir. That did it! I kneel before you! ( I will accept soon, I have to wait 10 min)

Answer (score 0):

```
$field_sql = 'SHOW FIELDS FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE FIELD = '.$column;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cna try with

```
$field_sql= 'SHOW FIELDS FROM ' . $table .  ' WHERE FIELD =' . $column;
```